# Extreme Memory Usage When Debugging Console Apps in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

OK folks, this one is driving me nuts.  I have classes that were auto generated by connecting to a third party web service which are fairly large (12 thousand lines and 530k).  When I instantiate these classes while *debugging* in a *console* app, I can watch the devenv.exe process's mem footprint balloon up to 3GB very quickly.

If I run the app from a command line, there are no problems; not even a blip in devenv.exe.  There are also no issues if I instantiate the classes in a web app whether or not I am in debug mode.

Odder still, I have found that, very rarely (twice out of maybe 50 times that I have tested this out today), after reproducing the issue on a console app, the issue will suddenly start happening on any web app in the same solution.  This is easily remedied by opening the solution properties and switching the configuration from Debug to Release and then back to Debug (that took a bit of fiddling and dumb luck to discover).

Maddeningly, this only seems to happen on **one** machine so I believe the issue to be something environmental either in the OS or VS.  I have reset all VS settings back to defaults with no luck.

This machine *is* the only one with VS 2012 installed (thought it has rarely been used and this solution has never been opened with it) so I am now wondering if that could be the culprit somehow.

My next step will be to uninstall/re-install VS2012 to see what happens, but I wanted to get this question out there to see if anyone thinks of something simple that I have not thought of.

Edit: I am running  VS2010 Pro SP1 32bit on Win7 Pro SP1 64 bit.

Comment: @TomasVoracek That is a good thought, but we are on VS pro so that is not even an option.

Comment: @TomasVoracek You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to turn off Intellitrace? It may cause heavy memory load in case of big solutions.

Comment: Thanks nikita, but VS pro does not have Intellitrace.